# Asp.net mvc calculated field in edit form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm trying to create asp.net mvc aplication. In worker.cs class I have added these parameters:

```
 public class Worker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public double Net { get; set; }
    [Editable(false)][NotMapped]
    public double Gross
    {
        get {
            if (Net <= 282.10 && Net > 0)
                return Math.Round(Net / 0.91, 2);
            else if (Net <= 335.30 && Net > 282.10)
                return Math.Round((Net - 46.5) / 0.76, 2);
            else if (Net <= 760 && Net > 335.3)
                return Math.Round((Net - 75) / 0.685, 2);
            else if (Net > 760)
                return Math.Round((Net / 0.76), 2);
            else
                return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Gross parameter should be readonly. My question is about edit form, I need to show *gross* value then user types *net* value (realtime).I have tried to use knockout.js, but I can't figure out how to do that.
[image]

```
div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Net, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Net, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: NetV, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Net, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gross, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Gross, new { @class = "form-control", data_bind="value:GrossV",@readonly = "readonly", disabled = "disabled" })

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**KnockoutJS** Follow **MVVM** Structure so u can just put calculation in view model.

**ViewModel:-**

```
var viewModel = function(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.net = ko.observable();
   self.gross = ko.computed(function() {
         if (self.net () <= 282.10 && self.net () > 0)
                return parseFloat(self.net () / 0.91).toFixed(2);
            else if (self.net () <= 335.30 && self.searchQuantity1 () > 282.10)
                return parseFloat((self.net () - 46.5) / 0.76).toFixed(2);
            else if (self.net () <= 760 && self.net () > 335.3)
                return parseFloat((self.net () - 75) / 0.685).toFixed(2);
            else if (self.net () > 760)
                return parseFloat(self.net () / 0.76).toFixed(2);
            else
                return 0;
    }, self);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

**View:-**

```
Net:-

<input id="test1" name="test1" type="text" data-bind="value: net, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"/>

<p>Gross: <span id="spantest3" data-bind="text: gross"></span></p>
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirenpateldev/ddwsdfjs/1/) That Working example !!

Hope Its Work !!

Haapy Coding !!!

Comment: Is there any way to get net value from database ant show as default observable value?

Comment: @Laurynas Simple pass value from controller and use @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.net, new { data_bind = "value:net" });

Comment: I have used this set up:  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Net, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: net, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" } }), everythink works, but default value shows empty text box

Comment: In ViewModel changes like that self.net = ko.observable('@ model.Net').

Comment: Still nothing, i have tried to change '@ model.Net' value to '565', but no result is visible

Comment: @Laurynas its means default value is set but gross is not calculated right??

Comment: gross value is calculated correctly, but default net value is not visible, unless user types it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137333/discussion-between-laurynas-and-dhiren-patel).

Answer (score 0):

This is something that needs to be calculated client-side (using javascript), not server side, if you want the gross figure to appear in real-time.

To do this, you need an event listener on the "Net" input. Something like this:

```
$('#net-input').change(function() {
    var gross;
    var net = $(this).val;
    // ..calculate gross..
    $('gross-input').val(gross);
}
```